# Using R in Visual Studio Code with conda environment

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I would like to use the R environment I installed with conda inside Visual Studio Code (on Macos). First I [installed R with conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/).
But how do I *use/activate* the environment in Visual Studio Code? In the settings I can't find the equivalent to ["Python: Select Interpreter" or "python.venvPath"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R support in VSCode is handled by a 3rd party extension. The most popular one is [R by Yuki Ueda](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r) and there is also [R Tools by Mikhail Arkhipov](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mikhail-Arkhipov.r)

For both of these, you can change the R interpreter to use in the settings.

However, there is no built-in support for Anaconda, mostly because it isn't that popular or necessary in the R community. Most people use the standard R installation instead and most help resources are written for that type of installation: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Comment: thanks, I installed the first extension you mentioned and the vsc setting is: `"r.rterm.mac": "/Users/user1/opt/miniconda3/envs/r_env/bin/R"`. Works now. There are already >2M downloads for r-base on anaconda, but compared to the regular userbase that might be still few.

Comment: hong-ooi, any particular reason you recommend against anaconda here?

Comment: Basically it conflicts with all the material you'll see posted online about how to manage your R setup. Conda puts files in nonstandard locations and you'll need to remember to change any code you see in order to handle that

Answer (score 7):

It has been 2 years since this entry and the extension still doesn't support `conda` environments.

For my configuration (I've `R` installed in a `conda` environment), I found a pretty painless work around:

- open 'vscode'
- install the extension and configure it as suggested using the `conda` paths for both `R` and, if you have it installed, `radian`
- close 'vscode'
- open a terminal
- activate your conda environment
- start `vscode` from your terminal using `code`

After this, everything seems to be up and running correctly. You can start an R terminal using the command palette and, as you run your code, you should be able to see all the information about the environment and namespaces as well as your plots.

Comment: Currently, this is the best way to use R installed with conda on VSCode.

Comment: A simple alternative that works for me is to 1) open a terminal in vscode, 2) activate the conda environment there, 3) open R in this terminal. R code in interactive mode is then sent to this terminal (if it is in focus).

Answer (score 0):

Detailed configuration steps similar to @Andrea's idea could be found at this [post](https://www.codydehaan.com/blog/vscode-miniconda-r/).

If you want to attach VSCode-R to your current R session (e.g., opened in a Conda environment), an [additional step](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/wiki/R-Session-watcher#advanced-usage-for-self-managed-r-sessions) to modify the `.Rprofile` is needed.